# Change the size of the controlgroup buttons?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this:

```
<div data-role="header" >   
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  >
<div id="b1" data-role="button"  >b1</div>
<div id="b2" data-role="button"  >b2</div>
<div id="b3" data-role="button"  >b3</div>
</div>
```

How would I change the size of the buttons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this in the css

```
div[data-role='controlgroup'] >  div{
    width:100px;
}
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/egvmL/

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Also found out that creating the buttons within a custom bar as in: `<div  class="ui-bar-a my-class-to-resize-button" >` will allow for the resizing to be applied via the `my-class-to-resize-button` class. I hope your answer and my question is of some help to anyone else who is stuck with this issue. Thanks user700284!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[data-role='controlgroup']>div")
```

then you can [apply css](http://jsfiddle.net/xR35C/1/).

from [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: Ok, well this only changes the controlgroup's box container. I was hoping there was a jquery-mobile theming directive that I can use to adjust the width and height of the buttons, as a group

Comment: You can use percentages (%) to adjust. But well, I don't know if there is a directive for this purpose, sorry.